# How to run a python script in C# .net?

Tags: c#, python.net

I just tried to execute the python script in C# .net project.
I set python dll environment path like below so `PythonEngine.Initiliaze()` func is working now.
But I don't know how to set python virtual environment in C#.
There are some python packages used in the python script so I need to set the virtual environment.
Here is my code so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", @"D:\workspace\Python\python311.dll", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    
    PythonEngine.Shutdown();
}
```